# C# How do you calculate number of days using Month Calendar in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, calendar, timespan

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express to create a Form that has the user choose a type of car(compact, standard, luxury) and a date on the calendar for how long they are going to rent it. I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the amount of days to find the total cost.

I tried `NumberDays = (Calendar.SelectionEnd - Calendar.SelectionStart);`

but I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'SystemTimeSpan' to 'int'"

I also tried to make today's date being the start date and a selection on the calendar being the end date but I'm not sure how to calculate the total days for that either.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
NumberDays = (Calendar.SelectionEnd - Calendar.SelectionStart).TotalDays;
```

Comment: `TotalDays` is a double, you need to convert it to int somehow (`Math.Ceiling` seems a good option in that case)

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("5/1/2011");
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("5/14/2011");


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int NumberDays = (int) dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalDays;
        MessageBox.Show(NumberDays.ToString());
    }
```